# Why isn't $\ell^p$ locally convex for $0<p<1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I believe we have to distinguish the finite-dimensional from the infinite dimensional case.

Regardless, if $0<p<1$, $\|x\|_p := (\sum |x_i|^p)^{\frac 1 p}$ is not a norm as it fails to satisfy the triangle inequality. That's why we use instead the metric $d(0,x) = \sum |x_i|^p = \|x\|_p^p$ to define the topology and remark that this is also not a norm since it is homogeneous of degree $p$.

I do not know how the balls defined by this metric look like, but they ought to be convex because the metric satisfies the triangle inequality, right? In other words, they can't be the corresponding astroid-shaped superellipses for $0<p<1$. So why is $\ell^p$ said to not be locally convex (at least in the infinite dimensional case)?

Comment: No, the balls for $d$ are not convex.  Even though $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality.  Try it on $\mathbb R^2$ ... graph the curve $|x_1|^{1/2}+|x_2|^{1/2} = 1$ to see.  As you note, in the finite dimensional case there is another equivalent metric that does have convex balls.  But not in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @GEdgar, right, squaring both sides gives the equation for the superellipse with $p=1/2$, so I agree with you. But shouldn't the triangle inequality have anything to do with convexity?

Comment: You should work these out yourself.  *In the presence of homogeneity (of degree one)*, subadditivity is, indeed, related to convexity of balls.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It actually works for homogeneity of any degree larger the one. BTW, if you are a professor you can be as more motivating to your students by leaving the grumpiness of "you should work these out yourself" aside (take this constructively).

Comment: As a professor, I find it often more instructive to the student to have them work something out, rather than just providing an answer.

Comment: @GEdgar, you are right! But you can have your students work something out without assuming that they will be nagging you for answers. Without having full knowledge of the student (which is impossible), how can you tell the amount of orientation that will be most benefitial to each of them? That's why I argue that math professors should just give hints and be kind, so as to also be a less grumpy and more inspirational class.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof why $l^p(\mathbb N)$ is not locally convex, this is just for simplicity, it can be easily generalized.

If it would be locally convex, then the unit ball $B_1(0)$ would contain a convex neighborhood U of $0$. Then there must be $\delta>0$ with $B_{2\delta}(0)\subset U$, hence also $\mathrm{conv}(B_{2\delta}(0))\subset U\subset B_1(0)$.

Let $e_i := (\underbrace{0,...,0,1}_{i},0,0,...)$. Then $\delta^{\frac 1p} e_i\in B_{2\delta}(0)$. We get $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\delta^{\frac 1p} e_i\in \mathrm{conv}(B_{2\delta}(0))\subset B_1(0)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, which means $1>\|\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\delta^{\frac 1p} e_i\|_p^p = \delta n^{1-p}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ which is a contradiction because $1-p> 0$.

Comment: But for the finite-dimensional case, what is the equivalent metric that for which is the unit ball is convex? And how can I generate the local basis of absolutely convex absorbent sets directly from the unit balls of the $p$-"norm" (quasinorm?)?

Comment: @Rodrigo, in the finite-dimensional case choose your favourite norm. They will all give the same topology.